# Xamarin.Forms AbsoluteLayout issue on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new with xamarin and I'm trying to use a searchbar with a result listview (which is hidden) on top of a main listview (ie: mobile facebook friend search)
On iOS I'm not being able to tap on the main listview because the result listview is always on top of the other one even if it's not visible.

Here is the code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0,50,0,0">
                    <StackLayout Padding="20,0,0,10">
                        <Label Text="{Binding SelectedAddressString, StringFormat='BCLs near {0}'}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <ListView x:Name="iOSlstBCLs" ItemsSource="{Binding BCLList}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Fill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
                    <SearchBar Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Search" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" />
                    <ListView IsVisible="{Binding IsSuggestionListVisible, Mode=OneWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding SuggestionList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAddress}" VerticalOptions="Fill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,AutoSize,AutoSize" BackgroundColor="White">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextCell Text="{Binding formatted_address}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you bind InputTransparent on the suggestions ListView to IsSuggestionListVisible?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you should never use an Absolute Layout if at all possible. It seems like it would be better to use a Stack and place both of your other stacks within that. Then set the visibility as needed. I am not positive, but I am guessing that the Absolute Layout is messing you up.

Comment: "From my experience, you should never use an Absolute Layout if at all possible."  - Can you elaborate on this? We just started working with Xamarin within the last few months and found absolute layout to be a great help, but only want to use it if there are no negative side effects.

Comment: I cannot remember where I got the information from, because it's been awhile, but I know that there are more performance issues with using Absolute Layouts. I can tell you that it is also discouraged on Android native platforms from using Absolutes Layouts which I am fairly sure is what is used to implement it. As of Forms Version 1.5.2, it says to prevent performance issues you should not use auto sizing whenever possible. https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-1.5/1.5.2-pre1/ Does that help at all?